# ¿Cómo modificar make:auth en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, controller, autenticación

Si se desea hacer un filtro previo antes de dar una respuesta para el login creado automáticamente con **Auth:routes()**,hay manera de hacerlo? suponiendo que quiero informarle al usuario que el correo con el que está intentando ingresar es invalido.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres modificar lo que hace el comando `make:auth` que se utiliza con artisan o quieres simplemente sobreescribir alguna parte de la autenticación? Son dos cosas muy distintas.

Comment: Pensaría que es añadir porque no he dado con la función que permita hacer lo que quiero y que sea cuestión de solo sobreescribirse,es algo sencillo pero no sé como se haría con el login automático de laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede hacer de forma simple en el controlador `RegisterController` ubicado en `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` modificás el método `validator` si querés hacer esta validación antes de la validación de Laravel o en el método `create` si queres hacerlo antes de la creación del usuario y listo.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    // Antes de la validación de Laravel
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    // Antes de la creación del usuario
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```